# Change div tag into table for IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a Div tables with display:table; but its not working ie7 or ie6.. And i don't want to use display-table.htc Hack for this...

**I want to change**

```
"<div class='divTable'> into <table class='divTable'>" 
"<div class='divRow ieclear'> into <tr class='divRow ieclear'>" 
"<div class='divCell'> into <td class='divCell'>"
```

Now I'm trying to convert 'Div' with 'Table' if browser.version == 7  || browser.version == 6... I'm new to Jquery..:D...

```
<div id="test">     
     <div class="divTable">
            <div class="divRow ieclear">
                <div class="divCell">Cell Wording1</div>
                <div class="divCell">Cell Wording2</div>
                <div class="divCell">Cell Wording3</div>
                <div class="divCell">Cell Wording4</div>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS//----

```
.divTable {
    font-family: Arial; 
    font-size: 12px;
    display: table;
    width: 981px;
    border: 10px soild #ECECEC;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    overflow: hidden; /* border-collapse:separate;*/}

.divRow {
    display: table-row;
    *display: block;*
    height: 100%;
    width: 981px;
}

.divCell {
    *float: left;*
    display: inline-block;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E9E9E4;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    background: #F5F6F0;
}

.ieclear {
    clear: both;
}
```

jQuery//

```
$(function () {
    //alert($.browser.version);
    jQuery("#test").find(".divTable").html('<table class="divTable">' + $(".divTable").html() + "</table>").html();
    //or
    $('div').replaceWith(function () {
        return $("<table />", { html: $(this).html() });
    });
});
```

Please suggest me or help me to solve this...:)

Comment: The obvious question is why aren't you just using a table? I would think you'd just iterate over the element children of the divTable element to get rows, then over their element children to get cells, then over their children to transfer the content. A recursive function should be quite small.

Comment: You shoudl change is to <table> format for all the browsers. Doing this on a client side is really a bad idea especially if you are  doing this on old browsers because they won't be able to take this much of DOM manipulation. Try to do it on server side.

Comment: Thanks @tea_totaler for your valuable suggestion. I know this is not good idea... But I can't make it in table...That's why i have posted here...may be anyone have better solution or idea for the same issue...lets see...

Comment: write two different pages (one with div and other with table) and when you see it's ie7 then redirect to the other page :D

Comment: Do you really need to be compatible with IE6 ? With IE7, you can trick your CSS to make the divs looks like a table without any `display: table/table-row/table-cell` instruction. With fixed size columns like you seems to have, floating all the cells with `float: left` and adding a `clear: left` to the rows should do pretty fine. IE6 however...

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
position:relative;
display: table-cell /*IE9+ and other browsers*/;
display: block /*IE8 and lower*/;
```